# How to create a session and share with iframe in magento 2 API

Tags: magento2.2, session, rest-api

The username and password will be send from third party service by cURL or something to Magento application. So now we need to create session in Magento application for shared customer details and also this session will be shared with iframe.

Because I am going to load this Magento application in an iframe.